# Creating A log File every day By php and Javascript

Tags: php

I am working with a project and i made a code to see who ais visiting my site
But i am facing a problam
The code works well but it collects all the information in one file
Now i just to make day by day log 
I mean every day a new file will be created and it automatically log in that file 
After one day a new file will be created

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$user_agent     =   $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
// Getting OS Name
 function getOS() { 
global $user_agent;
$os_platform    =   "Unknown OS Platform";
$os_array       =   array(
                        '/windows nt 10/i'     =>  'Windows 10',
                        '/windows nt 6.3/i'     =>  'Windows 8.1',
                        '/windows nt 6.2/i'     =>  'Windows 8',
                        '/windows nt 6.1/i'     =>  'Windows 7',
                        '/windows nt 6.0/i'     =>  'Windows Vista',
                        '/windows nt 5.2/i'     =>  'Windows Server 2003/XP x64',
                        '/windows nt 5.1/i'     =>  'Windows XP',
                        '/windows xp/i'         =>  'Windows XP',
                        '/windows nt 5.0/i'     =>  'Windows 2000',
                        '/windows me/i'         =>  'Windows ME',
                        '/win98/i'              =>  'Windows 98',
                        '/win95/i'              =>  'Windows 95',
                        '/win16/i'              =>  'Windows 3.11',
                        '/macintosh|mac os x/i' =>  'Mac OS X',
                        '/mac_powerpc/i'        =>  'Mac OS 9',
                        '/linux/i'              =>  'Linux',
                        '/kalilinux/i'          =>  'KaliLinux',
                        '/ubuntu/i'             =>  'Ubuntu',
                        '/iphone/i'             =>  'iPhone',
                        '/ipod/i'               =>  'iPod',
                        '/ipad/i'               =>  'iPad',
                        '/android/i'            =>  'Android',
                        '/blackberry/i'         =>  'BlackBerry',
                        '/webos/i'              =>  'Mobile',
                        '/Windows Phone/i'      =>  'Windows Phone'
                    );
foreach ($os_array as $regex => $value) { 
    if (preg_match($regex, $user_agent)) {
        $os_platform    =   $value;
    }
}   
return $os_platform;
}
// END of Getting OS
//
// Get browser
function getBrowser() {
global $user_agent;
$browser        =   "Unknown Browser";
$browser_array  =   array(
                        '/msie/i'       =>  'Internet Explorer',
                        '/firefox/i'    =>  'Firefox',
                        '/Mozilla/i'    =>  'Mozila',
                        '/Mozilla/5.0/i'=>  'Mozila',
                        '/safari/i'     =>  'Safari',
                        '/chrome/i'     =>  'Chrome',
                        '/edge/i'       =>  'Edge',
                        '/opera/i'      =>  'Opera',
                        '/OPR/i'        =>  'Opera',
                        '/netscape/i'   =>  'Netscape',
                        '/maxthon/i'    =>  'Maxthon',
                        '/konqueror/i'  =>  'Konqueror',
                        '/Bot/i'        =>  'BOT Browser',
                        '/Valve Steam GameOverlay/i'  =>  'Steam',
                        '/Googlebot/i'   =>  'GOOGLE Bot',
                        '/OrbitFox/i'   =>  'Orbit Fox Bot',
                        '/mobile/i'     =>  'Handheld Browser'
                    );
foreach ($browser_array as $regex => $value) { 
    if (preg_match($regex, $user_agent)) {
        $browser    =   $value;
    }
}
return $browser;
}
// END of getting browser
$user_os        =   getOS();
$user_browser   =   getBrowser();
// Comming soon part --- Maybe :D 

// Getting visitor IP address
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
// Getting where visitor come

// Hide ownr's IP address
$owner = "lol";   //Change $owner for something else, cuz someone can         simple read that by calling out $owner
 // change it for $absdfs5sd4 for example and change it down there 
$owner_country = "YOUR COUNTRY TAG FOR YOUR IP ↑"; //This u can leave how it is.

if($ip == $owner){ //Change it here 
    $ip = "Owner"; 
    $country = $owner_country;
    }
 //If that wasn't you, it woun't change IP address and it will find info about IP address
else{
    $details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}"));
    $country = $details->country;
 }

 $dataTime = date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Dhaka");
 $dataTime = date_default_timezone_get();
 $dateTime = date('D M d, Y  h:i:s a');

$file = "/home/shakilofficial/public_html/vtinfo/mainindex.html";
 $file = fopen($file, "a");
 $data = "<p>##################</p><br><p><b>User Time </b>: $dateTime </p><br><pre> <b> User IP </b>: $ip <b> Browser</b>: $user_browser <br> <b> User OS </b>: $user_os <b> Users-From </b>: $country <br><br><b> User-agent </b>: $user_agent </pre>";

fwrite($file, $data);
 fclose($file);

 ?>

<html>
 <body>
 <h1>Its Okh</h1>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: What is your question? what doesn't work?

Comment: assuming your webserver is Apache why not just parse the logs it generates? The same will more than likely be true for IIS or Zope or whatever webserver you have..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crate one more variable like the **$date** one:

```
$newTime = date('dmY');
```

And then add this in your file name:

```
$file = "/home/shakilofficial/public_html/vtinfo/mainindex{$newTime}.html";
```

So you will have a different file every day with different name

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to replace the line

```
$file = "/home/shakilofficial/public_html/vtinfo/mainindex.html";
```

with something along the lines of

```
$file = "/home/shakilofficial/public_html/vtinfo/mainindex-".date('Y-m-d').".html";
```

This will put all request from one date into an aptly named file.